# Select for multiple checkbox in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this sample data here in [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDiZoXux). When the grid load, there is 2 button `View` and `edit`. When I clicked on `view` checkbox in the grid only can select one node (working). But on the `edit` button when I clicked, I can select for multiple checkbox. Seem the function `onClick` still running and how to stop this?

[Demo in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDiZoXux)

```js
function onClick(e) {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");

  if(row.hasClass("k-state-selected")){
    setTimeout(function(e) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.clearSelection();
    })
  } else {
    grid.clearSelection();
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      //.........grid load code
  });

});


$("#view").kendoButton();
var button = $("#view").data("kendoButton");
button.bind("click", function(e) {
  $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  grid.tbody.on("click", ".k-checkbox", onClick);
});

$("#edit").kendoButton();
var button = $("#edit").data("kendoButton");
button.bind("click", function(e) {
  $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
});
```

```html
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <button id="view" class="k-button k-primary" value="view">View</button>
    <button id="edit" class="k-button k-primary" value="edit">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Please post your code in your post.

Comment: done, but I need to delete some line to make it short

Comment: Can you explain what interaction you wish to do with your code?

Comment: @mike. i wanted to make `view` button able to select one node at the time in the grid (this function is working) and 'edit' button able to select multiple nodes in the grid (still not working). Any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you dont `unbind` your `onClick` callback when `view` is clicked. When you bind an function to an event listener, it will continue to listen unless you remove that listener by `unbind`-ing it.

Try this:

```js
$("#edit").kendoButton();
var button = $("#edit").data("kendoButton");

button.bind("click", function(e) {

    // Unbind view event listener
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.tbody.unbind("click",  onClick);

    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
});
```

Side note, you should rename your `button` variables respectively in order to reduce likelihood to run into bugs.

Comment: i used different button variable this is just a sample only. Anyway thanks for highlight that point and helping me